# How to uninstall P-150M driver?

Tags: macos, driver, scanning, canon

I have 10.8.4 OS X and the [Canon P-150M](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/office/imageformula_scanners/imageformula_p_150_p150m/imageformula_p_150m_personal_document_scanner) scanner does not work with it. Yet my friend has an older iMac where it works. I want to try the new driver and test whether things start working. So how can I remove a driver in OS X?

[image]

Comment: Somebody have a solution for this major problem !? Thx

Answer (score -1):

For scanning with a P-150 on OS X 10.9 Mavericks:

1. Turn OFF the autostart under the scanner.
2. Disconnect the 2 USB cables and reconnect.

It should work correctly now.